# How can I preg_grep a date

Tags: php, grep

I try to grep a date.
`$m[0]` is `dpr_ts><'01/01/2002','31/12/2002']` .

I try to grep `01/01/2002` and `31/12/2002`:

```
$se = preg_grep("/(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})+/", $m);
```

I'm matching everything. I want to match the dates in an array `$se[0] = '01/01/2002'` and  `$se[1] = 31/12/2002`.

Comment: `preg_grep` greps an array and returns all values that match.  What is your input and expected output?

Comment: `$m[0]` is `dpr_ts><'01/01/2002','31/12/2002']`. Expected output $se[0] = '01/01/2002' and $se[1] = 31/12/2002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all("/(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})+/", $m[0], $se);

print_r($se);
```

Also, using `$m[0]` makes me suspect that this was a match from a previous `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`?  Maybe you could do it there and not have so many steps?

Comment: I'm using preg_match in an upper step. But I have an if case. I need to check some conditions first. I will think. Maybe I can omit some steps. Thank you!